# Showing $A$ is self-adjoint and the positive (negative) index of inertia of $b$ is equal to the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $1$ (at $-1$) of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on the following problem:

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space with a scalar product $(-,-)$, and $A:V\to V$ an operator such that $A^2=-I$. Define a bilinear form $b$ by $b(v,w)=(v,Aw)$, and show that if $b$ is symmetric then $A$ is self-adjoint, and the positive (resp. negative) index of intertia of $b$ is equal to the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $1$ (resp. $-1$) of $A$. (Every quadratic form on a finite-dimensional real vector space can be written in some basis as $x_1^2+\dots+x_k^2-x_{k+1}^2-\dots-x_{k+l}^2$, and we call $k$ and $l$ the positive, negative index of inertia.)

It's not difficult to see that $A$ is self-adjoint, since we can compute

$$(v,Aw)=b(v,w)=b(w,v)=(w,Av)=(v,A^*w)$$

for any $v,w\in V$, which implies $Aw=A^*w$. However, I'm having a bit of confusion at this point. Since $A$ is self-adjoint, if we choose an orthonormal basis and a matrix representation $B$ of $A$, then $B$ is symmetric, hence is diagonalizable by a real orthogonal matrix $Q$. That is, there is a diagonal matrix $D$ consisting of eigenvalues of $A$ such that $D=Q^t BQ$, where $Q^tQ=QQ^t=I$ (the source for this is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Real_symmetric_matrices)).

But then, using the hypothesis that $A^2=-I$, we can compute

$$D^2=(Q^tBQ)(Q^tBQ)=Q^tB^2Q=Q^t(-I)Q=-Q^tQ=-I.$$

How can this be possible though, since $D$ is diagonal consisting of real entries? That is, if

$$D=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1&&\\&\ddots&\\&&\lambda_n\end{pmatrix}$$

then we should have

$$D^2=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1^2&&\\&\ddots&\\&&\lambda_n^2\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}-1&&\\&\ddots&\\&&-1\end{pmatrix}=-I$$

However, this can't be true since the eigenvalues are real.

Can somebody help me see my mistake here?

Comment: You should clarify: algebraic multiplicity of eigenvalue, or geometric multiplicity of eigenvalue? They are two different concepts.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll aren't the two the same in the case of a self-adjoint operator?

Comment: Good point. They are identical in the case of a self-adjoint operator. I've now looked at your work and believe you are correct. My gut instinct is that this was a typo and the question is supposed to read $A^2=I$, not $-I$.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll that's very possible, I'll email my professor to double check. Thank you!